# Consulta parametrizada en Java SQL

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, netbeans, servlets

Tengo este método para cargar una lista:

```
public ArrayList<Articulos> articulosLista(Articulos a){
    ArrayList<Articulos> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    String consultarLista = "SELECT a.idA, a.codigo, a.denominacionA, a.precioUnitario, ta.denominacionTA, "
                            + "p.nombre1 + ' ' + p.apellido1, p.nombre2 + ' ' + p.apellido2 "
                            + "FROM articulo a "
                            + "INNER JOIN tipoArticulo ta "
                            + "ON a.idTA = ta.idTA "
                            + "INNER JOIN pareja p "
                            + "ON a.idPa = p.idP "
                            + "WHERE p.idP = ? ";
    abrirConexion();
    try(PreparedStatement consulta = conexion.prepareStatement(consultarLista)){
        consulta.setInt(1, a.getIdPareja());
        ResultSet rs = consulta.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
           Articulos articulos = new Articulos();
           articulos.setIdA(rs.getInt(1));
           articulos.setCodigo(rs.getString(2));
           articulos.setDenominacion(rs.getString(3));
           articulos.setPrecioUnitario(rs.getDouble(4));
           articulos.setIdTA(rs.getString(5));
           articulos.setP1(rs.getString(6));
           articulos.setP2(rs.getString(7));
           lista.add(articulos);
        }    
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error al mostrar las parejas: " + e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        try{
            cerrarConexion();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error al cerrar la conexión: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Y en mi `servlet` lo aplico así:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    
    String id = request.getQueryString();
    String idA = id;
    
    if(id.contains("id=")){
        id = id.replaceAll("id=", "").trim();
        String ida = id;
        Articulos articulos = new Articulos();
        articulos.setIdA(Integer.parseInt(ida));
        ArrayList<Articulos> lista = new ArrayList<Articulos>();
        Conexiones conexiones = new Conexiones();
        lista = conexiones.articulosLista(articulos);
        request.setAttribute("lista", lista);
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/listaParejasArticulosPrecios.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    };
}
```

Y este es el `jsp`:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
    <body>
        
            
        <div class="topnav">
            <a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home" style="font-size:24; padding-right: 10px;"></i>Inicio</a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label id="valorUrl" name="valorUrl" hidden>${param.id}</label>
        <center>
            <div class="container">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Pareja</th>
                            <th>Artículo</th>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach items="${lista}" var="A">
                            <tr>
                                <td>${A.denominacionA}</td>
                                <td>${A.p1}</td>
                                <td>${A.p2}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Actualización**

Y pasa por el `finally`, yendo hacial el `try` y aplica el método `cerrarConexion()`:

```
Ha ocurrido un error al mostrar las parejas: Incorrect syntax near '?'.
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Fijas siete parámetros pero sólo tienes un placeholder `?`. Dónde deberían ir los otros seis?

Comment: @Alfabravo En realidad los siete parámetros son del result set, para la consulta sólo quiere usar uno... pero no está usando ninguno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás haciendo uso de parametrización:

```
    //creas un statement, no un PreparedStatement
    statement = conexion.createStatement(); 
    //directamente ejecutas una query SQL, que incluye un ?
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("...");
```

La forma correcta sería algo como:

```
// updateString tiene el SQL con el placeholder (?)
try (PreparedStatement consulta = con.prepareStatement(updateString)) {
    consulta.setInt(1, productId); 
    // el 1 es porque hay un único ?, por lo tanto está en la primera posición
    // (la única que existe) de la lista de "placeholders"
    ResultSet rs = consulta.executeQuery();
    ... //resto de sentencias
} catch (SQLException e) {
    ...
}
```